# Android - No Activity found to handle Intent when opening FB native app

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to open FB app on a specific post from a url received in a notification.

It work perfectly on most devices but it crashes mostly on Samsung S7.
My simple code:

```
String url = "fb://post/<post_id>";
Uri target = Uri.parse(url);
notifIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, target);
startActivity(notifIntent);
```

I checked before that FB exists on the device:

```
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
try {
     int versionCode = packageManager.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0).versionCode;
     return "fb://post/" + fb_url;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
     return "https://www.facebook.com/" + fb_url; //normal web mUrl
}
```

The error log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{snip.snipnotifier/snip.snipnotifier.LoadingActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=fb://post/<post_id> }
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3149)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=fb://post/251996958535784_295668917501921 }
       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1817)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1515)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4076)
       at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4023)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:856)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4347)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4315)
       at snip.snipnotifier.LoadingActivity.onCreate(LoadingActivity.java:29)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since there is no Activity to handle your intent in Samsung S7 .You have check it first through this.

```
if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

Hope this help.Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean there is no Activity to handle my intent? There is no FB app installed?

Comment: Yes there is no FB application install so in the above code it will check whether there is someone to handle your intent then only the intent will fire.

Comment: I think the problem was in the code that checks if FB app exists... thanks!

Comment: @Rani welcome.You can accept the answer if it was helpful for you.

Comment: Should I use it for every link I have? It sound a bit expensive for me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41575190/android-check-if-facebook-app-exists-get-wrong-results