# Android - check if Facebook app exists returns wrong result

Tags: android, facebook

I'm opening links received in notifications in FB native app if it's installed on the app and in the browser otherwise, using this code:

```
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
try {
    packageManager.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    return context.getString(R.string.fb_app_prefix) + fb_url;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    return context.getString(R.string.fb_site_prefix) + fb_url; //normal web mUrl
}
```

It works on most devices (including the emulator), but in some of them it doesn't throw an error although the app isn't installed.

What's wrong with my code?

I can add the following code for every link I have but not sure it's "healthy":

```
Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(fb_app_url));
if (testIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    return fb_app_url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isPackageExisted(Context c, String targetPackage) {
 PackageManager pm = c.getPackageManager();
    try {
        PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo(targetPackage,
                PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What's the difference? this - PackageManager.GET_META_DATA?

Comment: Difference is: 
GET_ACTIVITIES
PackageInfo flag: return information about activities in the package in activities.

GET_META_DATA
ComponentInfo flag: return the metaData data Bundles that are associated with a component.

Yes, it works for me.

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks